# Removing joins in Django's admin panel query

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

I have some strange problem, that results from Django admin panel wanting to build a query to display list of items and ignoring my hints about it. It issues query containing `JOIN`s, even though I want it to avoid them in order to save underlying DB backend a lot of work.

Basically consider 3 models:

- `Book`
- `BookTemplate`
- `Author`

`Book` has some heavy column (containing whole book), while `BookTemplate` has something similar (eg. it contains definition of the layout that is then filled with content and `Book` is created).

Structure is similar to this:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    uuid = django_extensions.db.fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField(db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookTemplate(models.Model):
    uuid = django_extensions.db.fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField(db_index=True)
    content = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
    uuid = django_extensions.db.fields.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    created = django_extensions.db.fields.CreationDateTimeField(db_index=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    template = models.ForeignKey('BookTemplate')
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

It could be all fine, if not the fact, that when visiting Django admin page for listing `Book` instances, Django issues a database call like this:

```sql
SELECT
    "myapp_book"."uuid", "myapp_book"."content", (...)
INNER JOIN
    "myapp_booktemplate"
    ON ("myapp_book"."template_id" = "myapp_booktemplate"."uuid")
INNER JOIN
    "myapp_author"
    ON ("myapp_book"."author_id" = "myapp_author"."uuid")
ORDER BY
    "myapp_book"."created" DESC,
    "myapp_book"."uuid" DESC;
```

The problem with this query is that due to MySQL way of handling it, it causes huge temporary table to be created. I want to get rid of `JOIN`s.

However, overriding `ModelAdmin.queryset()` with something like that does not help:

```py
class BookModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(request):
        return super(BookModelAdmin, self).queryset(request).prefetch_related(
            'author', 'template',
        )
```

When checked, parent's `.queryset()` method returns `QuerySet` that is not yet containing any conditions requiring `JOIN`s.

I want to:

- force Django page for listing `Book` instances to do that with query (or queries) without `JOIN`s,
- remove default ordering by `uuid` (which is silly, as this value is completely random),

What am I missing? Is there some standard way to do that? I would like to save the time on writing custom implementation of administration panel and I am pretty confident that other people were hitting similar issues.